# Laravel and Mass Assignment Protection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There's something unclear with Laravel's (5) mass assignment protection. the protection, claimed to be on by default, only works when I'm "outside" of the application, from a custom artisan command for instance. The same mass assignment code that works from the "php application" will fail on mass assignment exception when running from a custom artisan command. Why is that? This difference isn't documented anywhere.

Why is there a security difference between the "Application" and the php artisan "commands"?

Is there a way to make the artisan commands work with mass assignment without changing the `fillable` or `guarded`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [unguard](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_unguard) command to get around having the add attributes to your fillable array.

```
Model::unguard();

// User::create(['some_protected_attribute'=>'some value']);

Model::reguard();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Add Model::unguard()` in your `AppserviceProvider.php`s boot method to disable mass assignment protection globally.

```
<?php 
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
 /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(){
     
        Model::unguard();
    }

}
```